# How many roots does the equation $a^x -x^n=0$ have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I want to know if there is a simple method to be able to tell the number of roots of an equation in the form of : $ a^x - x^n = 0 $ (with a>0 and n>0)
If we take $3^x=x$ for example. I know that graphically for example, you can see that there are no roots. But is there another (simple) way to solve it?
What about $5^x=x^2$?

Comment: For $3^x-x=0$, splitting it into three cases: $x > 1$, $0 \le x \le 1$, $x < 0$ will give the result.

Comment: Why separate $x > 1$ and $0=<x=<1$ ?
What about $5^x - x^2=0 $ for example?

Comment: I was thinking of using Bernoulli's Inequality for $x > 1$. For $5^x - x^2$, it is relatively straightforward to show that $5^x > x^2$ for $x \ge 0$, so there is only one root in the negatives ($5^x$ is increasing and $x^2$ is decreasing)

Comment: Have you seen calculus already? If so, the example is quite easy to solve: the derivative of the difference $3^x-x$ is $\ln 3\cdot 3^x-1$, which (since $3>e$) is positive for all $x>0$. This, together with the fact that $3^0>0$, shows that there are no solutions $\ge 0$; and there are obviously no solutions $<0$ since $3^x>0$ for *every* $x$, even $x<0$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Understood, thank you

Comment: The title is about $3^x-x$. The body is about the more general $a^x-x^n$. If you really want the latter question answered, please edit the misleading title.

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus?

Comment: @alex.jordan done , thank you.

Comment: @AmeetSharma yes, but is there another way without using it?

Answer (score 3):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

> I want to know if there is a simple method to be able to tell the
> number of roots of an equation in the form of : \begin{align} a^x -
> > x^n &= 0 \tag{1} \end{align}

This is exactly what
[the Lambert $\W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
(also known as ProductLog)
was introduced for.

\begin{align}
a^x &= x^n
,\\
x\ln a &= n\ln x
,\\
\tfrac1x\ln x
&=
\tfrac1n\ln a
,\\
\tfrac1x\ln \tfrac1x
&=
-\tfrac1n\ln a
,\\
\ln \tfrac1x
\exp(\ln \tfrac1x)
&=
-\tfrac1n\ln a
,\\
\W(\ln \tfrac1x
\exp(\ln \tfrac1x))
&=
\W(-\tfrac1n\ln a)
,\\
\ln \tfrac1x
&=
\W(-\tfrac1n\ln a)
,\\
\tfrac1x
&=
\exp\Big(\W(-\tfrac1n\ln a)\Big)
,\\
\tfrac1x
&=
-\frac{\tfrac1n\ln a}{\W(-\tfrac1n\ln a)}
,\\
x
&=
-\frac{\W(-\tfrac1n\ln a)}{\tfrac1n\ln a}
\tag{2}
.
\end{align}

The number of real roots of (1) is defined by the value of
$z=-\tfrac1n\ln a$,
the argument of $\W$ in (2):

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
z\ge0:\quad &\text{ one real solution, }
\quad 
x=\frac{\Wp(z)}z
,\quad 
x\ge0
,\\
z\in(-\tfrac1\e,0):
\quad &\text{ two real solutions, }
\quad 
x_0=\frac{\Wp(z)}z
,\ x_1=\frac{\Wm(z)}z,\quad 0<x_0<x_1
,\\
z=-\tfrac1\e:
\quad &\text{ one real solution, }
\quad 
x=
\frac{\Wp(-\tfrac1\e)}{-\tfrac1\e}
=
\frac{\Wm(-\tfrac1\e)}{-\tfrac1\e}
=\e
,\\
z<-\tfrac1\e:\quad &\text{ no real solutions}
,
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $\Wp$ is the principal branch
and $\Wm$ is the other real branch
of the Lambert $\W$ function.

For example, for $a=3$, $n=1$,
the solution of
\begin{align}
3^x&=x
\end{align}

must be

\begin{align}
x
&=
-\frac{\W(-\ln 3)}{\ln 3}
,
\end{align}

the argument of $\W$ in this case is
\begin{align}
z&=-\ln 3\approx -1.0986
<-\tfrac1\e
,
\end{align}

hence, there is no real solutions.

---

**Edit:**

As @alex.jordan pointed out, the expression (2)
does not cover all possible cases.

It misses the case of $x<0$
when $n$ is either even or
rational number with even numerator,
so in such cases
we need also to include the solutions $x=-t$
of the equation

\begin{align}
a^{-t}&=t^n
,\\
a^t&=t^{-n}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}
for positive $t$,
which we already know must be

\begin{align}
t
&=
-\frac{\W(-\tfrac1{-n}\ln a)}{\tfrac1{-n}\ln a}
=
\frac{\W(\tfrac1{n}\ln a)}{\tfrac1{n}\ln a}
,
\end{align}
so missing solution(s) are

\begin{align}
x
&=
-\frac{\W(\tfrac1{n}\ln a)}{\tfrac1{n}\ln a}
\tag{4}
.
\end{align}

For example, when $a=2,\, n=2$,
$z=-\tfrac12\ln 2\approx-0.34657\in(-\tfrac1\e.0)$

(2) provides two positive roots,

\begin{align}
x_0=-\frac{\Wp(-\tfrac12\ln 2)}{\tfrac12\ln 2}
=2
,\ x_1=-\frac{\Wm(-\tfrac12\ln 2)}{\tfrac12\ln 2}
=4
,
\end{align}

and since
the argument of $\W$ in (4) is
$\tfrac1{2}\ln 2>0$,
expression (4) gives just one more real root:

\begin{align}
x_3
&=
-\frac{\Wp(\tfrac1{2}\ln 2)}{\tfrac1{2}\ln 2}
\approx -0.7666647
.
\end{align}

Note that the arguments of $\W$
in (2) and (4) are $z$ and $-z$,
the maximal number of real roots of (1)
is $3$.

$\endgroup$

Comment: For example, if $a=n=2$, there are three real solutions. $x=2$, $x=4$, and a negative solution $x\approx-0.76\ldots$. This answer predicts at most two solutions in all cases.

Comment: @alex.jordan: thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $a$ is positive and $n$ is a natural number.

Note right away that for $a\neq1,n=0$, there is one solution, $x=0$. For $a=1,n>0$, there is one solution when $n$ is odd and two solutions when $n$ is even. And when $n=0,a=1$, it's a bit silly, but all real numbers are solutions.

So we continue assuming $n>0, a\neq1$. For $n>0$, $x=0$ is never a solution. Any solutions are either positive or negative.

If $x$ is a positive solution, then $$\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=\frac{\ln(a)}{n}$$

So we want to understand the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$. Its derivative is $\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^2}$. So $f$ increases on $(0,e)$, reaching a peak at $x=e$ with value $\frac{1}{e}$. And then decreases on $(e,\infty)$, with a limit of $0$. Also as $x\to0^+$, the limit is $-\infty$.

So $f$:

- has no positive solutions if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}>\frac{1}{e}$.
- has one positive solution if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}=\frac{1}{e}$.
- has two positive solutions if $0<\frac{\ln(a)}{n}<\frac{1}{e}$.
- has one positive solution if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}\leq0$.

Now could there be negative solutions? Only when $n=2k$ is even, since otherwise $x^n$ is negative for negative $x$, whereas $a^x$ will still be positive. In this case we similarly write $$\frac{\ln(-x)}{x}=\frac{\ln(a)}{2k}$$ and study $g(x)=\frac{\ln(-x)}{x}$ for negative values of $x$. Its derivative is $\frac{1-\ln(-x)}{x^2}$. So $f$ decreases on $(-\infty,e)$, reaching a low at $x=-e$ with value $-\frac{1}{e}$. And then increases on $(-e,0)$, with a limit of $\infty$. Also as $x\to-\infty$, the limit is $0$.

So provided $n$ is even, we can add a negative roots to the list. There is:

- one negative solution if $\frac{\ln(a)}{2k}=-\frac{1}{e}$.
- two negative solutions if $0>\frac{\ln(a)}{2k}>-\frac{1}{e}$.
- one negative solution if $\frac{\ln(a)}{2k}\geq0$.
- otherwise has no negative roots.

---

One big summary:

If $n$ is odd:

- no solutions if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}>\frac{1}{e}$. (Alternatively written as $a>e^{n/e}$.)
- one solution if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}=\frac{1}{e}$. ($a=e^{n/e}$)
- two solutions if $0<\frac{\ln(a)}{n}<\frac{1}{e}$. ($1<a<e^{n/e}$)
- one solution if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}\leq0$. ($a\leq1$.)

If $n\geq2$ is even:

- one solution if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}>\frac{1}{e}$. ($a>e^{n/e}$)
- two solutions if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}=\frac{1}{e}$. ($a=e^{n/e}$)
- three solutions if $0<\frac{\ln(a)}{n}<\frac{1}{e}$. ($1<a<e^{n/e}$)
- two solutions if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}=0$. ($a=1$)
- three solutions if $0>\frac{\ln(a)}{n}>-\frac{1}{e}$. ($e^{-n/e}<a<1$)
- two solutions if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}=-\frac{1}{e}$. ($a=e^{-n/e}$)
- one solution if $\frac{\ln(a)}{n}<-\frac{1}{e}$. ($a<e^{-n/e}$)

If $n=0,a\neq1$:

- one solution ($x=0$) no matter what $a$ is.

If $n=0,a=1$:

- all real $x$ are solutions

---

Arranged an alternative way:

All real numbers are solutions when:

- $n=0,a=1$

There are three solutions when:

- $n$ is even and $e^{-n/e}<a<e^{n/e}$ but $a\neq1$

There are two solutions when:

- $n$ is odd and $1<a<e^{n/e}$
- $n$ is even, at least $2$, and either $a=e^{n/e}$, $a=1$, or $a=e^{-n/e}$

There is one solution when:

- $n=0$
- $n$ is odd and $a\leq1$ or $a=e^{n/e}$
- $n$ is even, at least $2$, and either $a>e^{n/e}$ or $a<e^{-n/e}$

There are no solutions when:

- $n$ is odd and $a>e^{n/e}$

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are supposing $a>0$ and $n$ is a rational number which can be expressed as $\frac{p}{q}$ where $q$ is an odd here or the question will become pretty tricky.

Then consider what will happen when $x>0$.

We can move $x^n$ to the RHS and take logarithm functions on both sides and get $xlog(a)=nlog(x)$.

Hence we have $\frac{log(x)}{x}=\frac{log(a)}{n}$

For $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{log(x)}{x}=\frac{1-log(x)}{x^2}$ we can deduce that the function $\frac{log(x)}{x}$ has its maximum $\frac{1}{e}$ at $x=e$.

Hence, this function has 2 roots when $\frac{log(a)}{n}<\frac{1}{e}$, 1 root when $\frac{log(a)}{n}=\frac{1}{e}$ and no root when $\frac{log(a)}{n}>\frac{1}{e}$ if $x>0$.

Then consider $x<0$ (x cannot be equal to zero).

When $p$ is an odd, $x^n$ is definitely negative and $a^x$ is definitely positive. So $a^x-x^n=0$ has no root when $x<0.

When p is an even, we use the substitution $y=-x$. Hence the equation becomes $a^{-y}-(-y)^n=0$ which can be written as $(\frac{1}{a})^y-y^n=0$. Hence, this function has 2 roots when $-\frac{log(a)}{n}<\frac{1}{e}$, 1 root when $-\frac{log(a)}{n}=\frac{1}{e}$ and no root when $-\frac{log(a)}{n}>\frac{1}{e}$ if $x<0$. (Note that $log(\frac{1}{a})=-log(a)$)

According to the equation you give, $a=3$ and $n=1$ so $\frac{log(a)}{n}=log(3)$ which is greater than $\frac{1}{e}$. Since 3 is an odd, this equation has no root.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you so much

Comment: Additionally when x<0 it is not that tricky when n is a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ and the denominator is an odd. I will edit it later.

Comment: I'm actually supposing n is a natural number. Forgot to mention

Comment: I edited it again, and this time I suppose n is a rational number. If you suppose $q=1$ and $p=n$ the result is still the same.